# Using different header images for different devices

Tags: theme-customizer, headers

I'm using the Ascension theme (by Go Daddy). When my website is loaded using a PC or ipad my header looks ok, however when loading it on a phone it is not resizing to fit the screen (so I'm losing a bit from both ends) and also my page title is not in the correct place (top rather than middle). I would like to use two images to be displayed on to different devices. Can this be done in CSS or is it theme template modification? Just for the purposes of this question just say that I have two pics:

header-pc.jpg
header-moblie.jpg

Many Thanks,

Paul

site: http://www.catherineparkersolutions.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I’ll debug the source code after for detail anwser but I guest you can try this CSS solution:

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  css selector {
    background-image: url("header-mobile.jpg");
  }
}

Comment: Thanks Linherest, This code works:

Comment: '@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {.hero {background-image: url("http://www.catherineparkersolutions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/header-hs-tx-3-moblie-copy.png");
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;}}'

However it works 4 portrait only. So (in addition):

'@media screen and (max-width: 375px) and (orientation: landscape) {.hero {background-image: url("http://www.catherineparkersolutions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/header-hs-tx-3-moblie-copy.png");
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;}}'

but that did not work (4 landscape) any ideas?

Comment: Check your screen width in landscape mode. Then you change the max-width to this value. For example, your mobile has screen resolution 375 x 667. Then you can change the max-width to 667px. CSS will work for both cases: portrait & landscape.  You can use http://www.screenresolution.org to check you mobile’s screen resolution.

Comment: That worked a treat  Do you know whether there is a standard list of sizes that I should include in my @media statements which would cover 95% of all mobile devices?

Comment: Based on Chrome Dev tool, we have some popular screen size like: Mobile S - 320px; Mobile L - 375px; Normaly, Wordpress Theme using max-width: 500px to cover the most mobile screen size.